# R removing items in a sublist from a list

Tags: r

I have a list:

```
L <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
```

I also have a subset of this list:

```
L1 <- c("b","d","e")
```

I am trying to create a new list that does not contain the subset list.

I have tried:

```
L[L!%in%L1]
L[L%in%!L1]
L[L%in%-L1]
```

but this does not work.
I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: You'are asking for a vector, not a list

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It should be

```
L[!(L %in% L1)]
```

Because of operator precedence (`?Syntax`), you can also do

```
L[!L %in% L1]
```

Finally, you also have:

```
setdiff(L, L1)
```

Comment: But `setdiff` will fail if there are repeated elements in either list.

Comment: "Fail" is a bit of a harsh statement for 1) The OP's example has no duplicates and 2) he is asking for a "subset": where the mathematical definition of a "set" excludes duplicates. Let's just say that if `L` had duplicates, the output would be different. And let the OP decide or clarify.

Comment: Hmph :-) I'm often accused of being a concrete thinker, engineering-style, and here I tried to point out that in a more general case there'd be a problem... :-( .  After all, the very self-named `R` function `subset` doesn't follow algebraic rules!

Comment: Ok. I think you are right to point the more general case, and that it would give a different output. But I don't think you should call it a problem or a failure.

Answer (score 3):

You could also play with `vecsets:vsetdiff`  (disclaimer: I wrote this scary package).  Unlike proper set theory as implemented in `setdiff`,  `vsetdiff` will return all elements of a vector which do not appear in the second argument, thus allowing for multiple instances of a given value.

```
vsetdiff(L,L1)
[1] "a" "c"
vsetdiff(L1,L)
character(0)
```